# How do I program realtime & concurrency in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to program soft-realtime program in KDB. I've got everything set up, the only problem I'm having is setting up an event loop.

In Python, I'd do something like:

```
while True:
  do something
```

Even better would be if it was non-blocking (or allocated to a CPU core), so I could run several of these simultaneously.

How should I be thinking about this in KDB?

PS I can't find docs covering this, but please do link to them if they exist.

Comment: Is this what you’re looking for? https://code.kx.com/q/ref/while/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's not common or best practice to use while loops in kdb, though the functionality is there.

More often than not you would make the kdb instance:

A. event-driven (main logic goes in `.z.pg`/`.z.ps`/`.z.po`/`.z.pc` so that kdb reacts to sync/async events and connection/disconnection events), or

B. timer-driven (main logic goes in `.z.ts`), or

C. A combination of the above.

This would be a "non-blocking" setup, as opposed to a while loop which would block as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: I have a simple question then; is KDB really suited for the purpose of writing concurrent server applications with complex state? Or do most people use it as a data-store and outsource most of the business logic to another language?

Comment: If there's enough skills in a team, enough knowledge/experience and commitment to kdb then yes, kdb is suited for almost any system you need to design (except perhaps in cases where you need a super low-latency, low-level system which could be better written directly in C, for example an OMS or a feedhandler). To use kdb solely as a datastore is a waste of potential - might as well use mySQL or any other off-the-shelf DB. Kdb is best used by bringing data and logic into one place (aka bring the analytics to the data rather than bring the data to the analytics)

Answer (score 1):

I think Terry's explanation of why not to use while loops sums up the topic very well.

For concurrency there are a few options:

- *peach* https://code.kx.com/q/basics/peach/ can be used in place of *each* to farm out processing to secondary threads if you have started with the -S (secondary thread) command line argument
- As of KDB+ 4.0 there are now multithreaded primitives by default: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/mt-primitives/
- The 'traditional' way to achieve concurrency with KDB+ is to spin up multiple single threaded KDB+ processes which can communicate with each other via asynchronous IPC calls https://code.kx.com/q/basics/ipc/. Some examples of systems built like this are KDB+ Tick https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick and AquaQ Analytics' TorQ framework: https://aquaqanalytics.github.io/TorQ/Overview/